# Scala: Chain Options with logging

Tags: scala

I want to chain few `Options` to compute final value. It's simple:

```
def compute(aOpt: Option[String], bOpt: Option[String], 
            cFun: (String, String) => Option[String]): Option[String] = {
  for (a <- aOpt; b <- bOpt; c <- cFun(a, b)) yield a + b + c
}
```

But I need to add debug information - log whatever data is missing. Something like code below, which works but it's a little bit clumsy:

```
def compute(aOpt: Option[String], bOpt: Option[String],
            cFun: (String, String) => Option[String], logger: Logger): Option[String] = {
  if (aOpt.isEmpty) {
    logger.error("a is empty")
  }
  if (bOpt.isEmpty) {
    logger.error("b is empty")
  }
  val cOpt = for ( a <- aOpt; b <- bOpt) yield cFun(a,b)
  if (cOpt.isEmpty) {
    logger.error("c is not found")
  }
  for (a <- aOpt; b <- bOpt; c <- cOpt) yield a + b + c
}
```

I'm looking for elegant and idiomatic way of accomplishing it.

Edit: I improved the code because in previous version it sometimes called `cFun` twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's ok to log just the first "emptiness" then you can define an implicit helper class for `Option[T]` as:

```scala
implicit class LogOption[T](opt: Option[T]){
  def orLogError(msg: String)(implicit logger: Logger) = { // Require an implicit Logger
    if(opt.isEmpty) logger.error(msg); opt // Always log as error
  }
}
```

and then write your for-comprehension as:

```scala
for {
  a <- aOpt orLogError "a is empty"
  b <- bOpt orLogError "b is empty"
  c <- cFun(a, b) orLogError "c is not found"
} yield a + b + c
```

Comment: @mjjaniec if you prefer to pass explicitly the `logger.error` function I can provide you an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute(aOpt: Option[String], 
            bOpt: Option[String],
            cFun: (String, String) => Option[String], logger: Logger): Option[String] = {

        val optList = List((aOpt, "a"), 
                           (bOpt, "b"), 
                           (cFun(aOpt.getOrElse(""), bOpt.getOrElse("")), "c"))

        optList.foreach(x => if(x._1.isEmpty) logger.error(x._2 + " is Empty"))

        for (a <- aOpt; b <- bOpt; c <- cFun(a, b)) yield a + b + c
   }
```

Comment: I didn't choose this solution because it has 2 drawbacks: `cFun` could be called twice and `cFun` is called with "artificial" arguments.

Comment: That's alright. @Federico's solution is more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

@Federico Pellegatta answer satisfies me - first error is good enough for me. But just for reference I submitting modification of his solution that logs all errors:

```
implicit class LogOption[T](opt: Option[T]){
  def orLogError (msg: String)(implicit logger: Logger) = { // Require an implicit Logger
    if(opt.isEmpty) logger.error(msg); opt // Always log as error
  }
}

val cOpt = for (a <- aOpt; b <- bOpt) yield cFun(a, b)

aOpt orLogError "a is empty"
bOpt orLogError "b is empty"
cOpt orLogError "c is empty"

for (a <- aOpt; b <- bOpt; c <- cOpt) yield a + b + c
```

Comment: If you really want to use it like this, change the `orLogError` to not return `opt`: `def orLogError(msg: String)(implicit logger: Logger) = if(opt.isEmpty) logger.error(msg)`.